# How to revert a Project Facets convertion in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, project, facet

I have a Java 8 project for Desktop, in Eclipse. Following instructions to fix another problem, I right clicked on my project and Properties -> Project Facets and I checked the Dynamic Web Module. Now I'm having some problems with the project and I'd like to reverse the actions I've taken. How do I get the project back to how it was before that change I made?

Answer (score 8):

You have to edit the **.project** in your repo project and do the following:

- Remove the unwanted buildCommand entries.
- Remove the unwanted nature entries.
- Then restart your eclipse or close open your project.